# Make a background Image to fit multiple objects?

Tags: unity, c#

In the Hierarchy, I have a `GameObject` named "Buttons" to which I added an  `Image` component.

[image: Buttons]

I would like that the `ok` sprite to cover (be background of) all the buttons: `START GAME`, `OPTIONS`, `CREDIT` and `EXIT`.

But the `ok` sprite is somewhere in the top left corner behind the `START GAME` button on its left side and is very small.
This happened when I clicked in the Inspector in `Image` on `Set Native Size`.

I want to make it big enough to cover all the buttons but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply stretch the image using [anchor presets](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIBasicLayout.html). Hold <kbd>alt</kbd> (important!) and click on the blue box in the bottom right corner. This will stretch the UI element so that it fills the entire area.

[image: anchor presets]